# Davinci Resolve 15 Beta workflow bar covering up color settings

Tags: davinci-resolve

I have Davinci Resolve 15 Public Beta. The bar on the bottom that enables you to switch from editing to color grading is covering up the settings for RGB, and I cannot drag the window up to make the settings visible. Is this a bug? I have looked through just about every Davinci Resolve tutorial and nobody has this problem.

Aside from uninstalling and reinstalling Resolve, is there a way to make the settings visible?
[image: The bar covers everything up]

Comment: Does your display resolution meet the minimum system requirements?  For mac, your user interface monitor needs to be at least 1440x900.  For PC, the minimum is 1920x1200, according to this document: http://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/DaVinciResolve/20180407-79c607/DaVinci_Resolve_15_Configuration_Guide.pdf

Comment: I see. My monitor is 1360x768. (I'm using a workstation laptop.) I won't be getting a different computer anytime soon, but increasing my external monitor's resolution seems to fix the issue. Thanks!